# Json string gets escaped in web-api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-mvc-5

we have JSON configuration data stored in a database. i need to fetch this JSON data and return it, as it is, to the browser via asp.net web-api:

```
public class ConfigurationController : ApiController
{
    public string Get(string configId)
    {
        // Get json from database
        // when i return the fetched json it get's escaped
    }
}
```

The value that i return gets escaped. how do i simply return the string as it is? I really don't want to populate an object that gets serialized to JSON.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can return a `HttpResponseMessage` from the ApiController which allows you to basically return a string value.

e.g.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage() { 
        Content = new StringContent("Hello World", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") 
    };
}
```

What you would want to do is just pass the json string as the StringContent.

Comment: This solved 2 separate issues i was having with this framework. Thanks! Do you know why this is required though? It seems pointless that the framework has xml and json as built in response formats, when they can only return a string and nothing more complex.

Comment: The answer from wilsotc is better because the mime type is wrong in this one for returning JSON.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is slightly off. The correct version is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage() { 
        Content = new StringContent("Hello World", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") 
    };
}
```

It's the StringContent function that correctly removes the escaping. Without the application/json media type, tools like postman won't correctly display the "pretty" version of the result.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
return Request.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.OK, stringContent );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetTravelers(string authkey)
{
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(travelList, Global.JsonSettings);
 return new HttpResponseMessage()
 {
   Content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, 
"text/html")
       };
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes,Its Working You Have To Change Method Type To HttpResponseMessage Instied of string or int type

You Have to serialize Your Query Value into Json